# Why does Sublime forget my session every time?

Tags: session, sublime-text

Every time I close Sublime Text 2 and reopen it, my project folders are not shown, as are the open files I was using last time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a bug to me. I have been experiencing the same issue and [we are not alone](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12392):

> This is a bug with Windows ST3 Build 3033 (and probably all the other
>   OSes and builds as well).
>
> When I open a file - and then close the entire application (such as
>   with Alt+F4 or File>Exit) - the files that were opened before closing
>   the application do not get added to the "Open Recent" list.
>
> However - if I go to File-->Close - then if I close SublimeText and
>   open it again - then the files get added.
>
> It seems the files are getting added to the Open Recent list during a
>   "Close" event which is not getting triggered during an application
>   exit. Also, FYI I have "remember_open_files": false, and "hot_exit":
>   false. So I expect that when I close the entire application - it
>   should add those files to the Recent list that were open when I exited
>   the app.
>
> **Steps to reproduce:**
>
> 1. Open a file in SublimeText.
> 2. Go to File - Exit.
> 3. Reopen SublimeText and check the menu File>Open Recent - file will not be there.

You can find the corresponding bug report [here](https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues/44).

Comment: That's correct. Was able to reproduce the bug. But, I'm in Ubuntu with ST2

Answer (score 4):

Try this command :

```
 sudo chown $USER -R ~/.config/sublime-text-2/
```

see if that works for u.

Update:

What happens is if/when you start sublime using sudo access, then sublime saves the temporary files for that session with sudo permissions. Now when you open sublime with a user without overwrite access to those files, sublime fails to save your session (Can't overwrite files written by root user). Hence when you start sublime next time it starts a clean session.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update of the nice answer from @Vikash Singh. For the last Sublime version:

```
sudo chown $USER -R ~/.config/sublime-text-3/
```